# Which data structure to throttle outbound messages?

Tags: throttling, outbound

I need to send messages (the actual technology is irrelevant at this stage) while complying with a number of throttling constraints.
Basically I have contraints that are related to the sender and to the destination, in terms of messages per second.
I don't mind in enforcing the throttling while accepting the messages from the sender, while I do need to throttle them when sending out.
I was thinking about priority queues, but maybe there's a better advice.

Anyway, the application is multithreaded, written in C and running under Linux, if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question and the answers mentioned there:

[Throttling method calls to M requests in N seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407113/throttling-method-calls-to-m-requests-in-n-seconds/5975169#5975169)