# meteor for very fast data

Tags: node.js, meteor, redis, livequery

I just started with Meteor app development and have a use case which I am not sure is good for meteor.

We have a java application that pushes data to redis at a very fast rate (data updates in less than 50 milliseconds) and we are building a web application (on NodeJS) which connects to this redis instance and sends the data to the client. For now (with native NodeJS app), we are sending data only twice a second (as we do not require such fast updates).

My question is, how can I achieve the same with Meteor? As we know Meteor has live-query which will tend to send data as soon as it changes, but this is not optimum for us. Is there a way to tune live-query to send data say only after a certain time?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do that you can implement your own observer for changes http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ways to throttle meteors calls. This could be done with [this library](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/Meteor-Throttle).

This issue has been also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959184/how-can-you-throttle-calls-server-side). Reading up on it I think they still haven't implemented it in core. This would make sense since there are no out-of-the-box throttling mechanisms in node or iojs.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Jefe
Your links look promising but I am not sure if thats what I want.
You see, my use case is - 
Some other application updates the Redis Server, and I want to send the updates from Redis using Meteor every 50 milliseconds or so.
Hence, I don't need to throttle any request coming to the server, but instead the server should push updates at a throttled rate!