# How to limit rate of outgoing REST API request in scaled microservice environment

Tags: spring, rest, microservices, autoscaling, rate-limiting

I have a scenario in which my Spring boot microservice is scaled to 8 instances. Each service consume the message from MQ and makes a http call to third party service. However, the third party service has a rate limit i.e. it cannot accept more than 20 requests per second. Now that I have 8 instances of same service running its hard to keep track of count. Any solutions that could help me implement this in autoscale environment ?

Comment: Does this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407113/throttling-method-calls-to-m-requests-in-n-seconds

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advice to keep track of that state because that's virtually impossible.
Have a look at [Circuit Breakers](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker) which is included in Spring Cloud. They can add behaviour to outgoing calls including some retry and backoff settings, or return stubs if all else fails. Implementations include Spring-Retry and Netflix Hystrix among others.
I guess it's still not 100% fault-tolerant but as you already use messaging that won't be an issue because if all retries fail you can nack the message.

There's also [this introduction](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) from Martin Fowler to Circuit Breakers which is really nice.
Hope this might give you something new to concider.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://dougbarth.github.io/2011/06/10/keeping-the-rabbit-on-a-leash.html) comes to my mind. They use a [Token Bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) to control the flow. The use case sounds similar to yours.

> Our connection to our SMS aggregator requires us to limit the rate that we send messages to their system.