# Android app with Facebook comments

Tags: android, facebook-comments

I have an Android app which gets database items with unique ids. So, i want to make users leave Facebook comments about these items by using their unique ids.

What is the best way to do that? I looked up Facebook Android SDK docs but it doesn't say anything about comments.

These items are not Facebook posts. I wanna make Android version of facebook comments of web sites.

Need your help.

Comment: You want them to make Facebook Comments? Are these items somehow on Facebook (e.g. did they post a status update regarding these items?).

Comment: No, they are not on Facebook. Web sites use url adresses. I wanna make a Android version of it. I am looking for the best way to make users to leave comments and show these comments.

Comment: Were you successful doing it? cuz i am also looking to do that. I want fetch facebook comments from blog site and display it in app also i want to comment from app using facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want your users to make Facebook comments on items within your android app, much like they would use Facebook to leave comments on a non-Facebook website.

One way to do this is to authenticate users to Facebook, and allow them to leave comments which will be cached on your website or a visible server somewhere. These comments will be tagged with an ID unique to the user, and supplemented with their Profile Picture and Username, which will then link to Facebook itself. However, none of the comments will be visible on Facebook, only your app.

If you want to use Facebook as an unofficial ad platform, you can create a Facebook app which collects data from your Android app, and allow users to post Open Graph Stories about your products to Facebook.

In order to do this, you will need to [authenticate your users to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate) via your app, then [configure your app to allow to post on their behalf](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/publish-open-graph-story) regarding the item in your Android app.

Essentially, when a website allows users authenticated to Facebook to leave comments, what they are doing is identifying users via their Facebook credentials, however the comments are stored on the website, not Facebook itself. You'll need some way to store these comments on the web in order for your Android app to show this data to other users.