# Simulating streaming data

Tags: c, perl, stream, simulation, named-pipes

I'm trying to write a program that will read from a flat file of data and simulate streaming it so I can test a program that reads streaming data without having to connect and start up the streaming hardware.

What are the more realistic ways to accomplish this? I need it to stream at variable speeds depending on the hardware im simulating.

My two ideas so far are a program that writes to a named pipe, or a program that writes to a virtual serial port at the rates I need.

Is there a better (more realistic) way of simulating streaming data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a background process that writes the file to a socket at whatever rate you want. In Perl,

```
use Socket;
socketpair my $A, my $B, AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC;

if (fork() == 0) {
    stream();
    exit;
}

while (<$A>) {
    print;
}

sub stream {
    # output 1024 bytes/sec
    select $B; $| = 1;          # disable output buffering
    open my $fh, '<', '/file/to/stream';
    my $buffer;
    while (my $n = read $fh, $buffer, 1024) {
        sleep 1;
        print $B $buffer;
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect- Is it simple to read from the $A socket from a different process?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with simulating the stream in a way that is closest to the original source of stream data. E.g. if you normally get your stream from a network socket, then use a network socket to simulate; if you have a serial port, then use a virtual serial port, etc. Otherwise, you will need an adapter for your stream consumer code (but you already know all this I presume).

Other than that, you'll need a rate limiting algorithm that will allow you to control how much data to send. A quick search led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm) but there are surely more complex and sophisticated algorithms. YMMV.

This assumes of course that you know how to create valid data/packets for the consumer of your stream.

Answer (score 0):

You might try saving some coding time by looking at [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle) (a userspace bandwidth shaper).