# How can I simulate a 16-bit data stream?

Tags: c#, powershell, real-time, data-stream

I am trying to test some signal processing functions that I have written and I want to simulate real time streaming data of signed 16-bit values representing a Sine wave sampled at 960 Hz. So I imagine somewhere along the way there will be something along the lines of

```
short output = (short)32000*Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * time);
```

where `time` would be some single or double precision floating point number in seconds.

Is there someway to do this with C#, a Windows PowerShell script or otherwise? And how would I capture that data? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505195/simulating-streaming-data) but I don't know Perl and I'm not sure I understand.

Or am I understanding how real time data streams work wrong?

Comment: If you are sampling at 960Hz you will be producing 1 sample/ms (roughly!) - the normal timers in C# typically have a resolution of around 15ms, so are unsuitable. You will probably need to use a High Resolution Timer: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137121/high-resolution-timer for more info.

Comment: @RB. Does `DataTime.ToOADate()` not go down to that resolution? If a day is one unit, then 1/24/60/60/960 is on the order of 10^(-8), but the return value of `ToOADate()` is a `double` which goes down to ~15 decimal places, or am I not understanding something correctly?

Comment: Well, what do you want to test? The algorithm? The sampling? If the latter, what's the way the function obtains the data?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I want to test my signal processing functions. I need a data stream of 16-bit values to feed into it.

Comment: How does the function obtain the data?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've never done anything with streaming data before, but I imagine I would open a stream to the data. The actual signal processing function just takes a `short` value as an argument and outputs a processed value and it would be called every time the stream streams a data value.