# How do we use sleep() in Linux to keep our CPU usage reasonable while still having decent timing accuracy?

Tags: python, linux, windows

## The Problem

I'm trying to test a system that uses UDP packets to communicate at a predetermined rate. I want to be able to test this system using a Python test harness with a set packet rate. Sample rates might be 20 packets/sec, or 4500 packets/sec, etc.

In some simple tests I've determined that my Windows machine can pass upwards of 150,000 UDP packets per second over localhost, so I can treat that as an upper limit for the sake of the experiment.

Let's start with this shell structure to create a rate limiter. This code is inspired mostly by code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm).

### Approach 1

```
import time, timeit

class RateLimiter:

    def __init__(self, rate_limit):
        self.min_interval = 1.0 / float(rate_limit)
        self.last_time_called = None

    def execute(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.last_time_called is not None:
            # Sleep until we should wake up
            while True:
                now = timeit.default_timer()
                elapsed = now - self.last_time_called
                left_to_wait = self.min_interval - elapsed

                if left_to_wait <= 0:
                    break

                time.sleep(left_to_wait)

        self.last_time_called = timeit.default_timer()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can use this helper class like so:

```
self._limiter = RateLimiter(4500)   # 4500 executions/sec

while True:
    self._limiter.execute(do_stuff, param1, param2)
```

The call to `timeit.default_timer()` is a shortcut in Python that gives you the highest accuracy timer for your platform, lending an accuracy of about 1e-6 seconds on both Windows and Linux, which we will need.

#### Performance of Approach 1

In this approach, `sleep()` can buy you time without eating CPU cycles, but it can hurt the accuracy of your delay. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15967564/31707) shows the differences between Windows and Linux regarding `sleep()` for periods less than 10ms. In summary of that comment, Windows' `sleep()` only works for values of 1ms or more (any less is regarded as zero) but generally sleeps for *less* than the requested sleep time, while in Linux `sleep()` is more precise but generally sleeps for slightly *more* than the requested time.

The code above is accurate on my Windows machine, but is inefficient for faster rates. When I requested a rate of 4500 packets/sec in my tests, I got a median of 4466 packets/sec (0.75% error). *However*, for rates faster than 1000Hz, the calls to `sleep()` take zero time, so the RateLimiter burns CPU cycles until exceeding the wait time. Unfortunately we have no other choice since we can't use non-zero sleep times less than 1ms in Windows.

In Linux, the calls to `sleep()` took longer than requested, yielding a median of 3470 packets/sec (22.8% error). While `sleep()` in Linux takes longer than desired, requesting higher rates like 6000Hz yields a true rate higher than 4500, so we know that it's capable of the goal rate. The problem is in our `sleep()` value, which must be corrected to be lower than we might have expected. I performed another test, using the following (bad) approach.

### Approach 2

In this approach, we never sleep. We chew up CPU cycles until the time elapses, which leads Python to use 100% of the core it's running on:

```
def execute(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.last_time_called is not None:
        # Sleep until we should wake up
        while True:
            now = timeit.default_timer()
            elapsed = now - self.last_time_called
            left_to_wait = self.min_interval - elapsed

            if left_to_wait <= 0:
                break

            # (sleep removed from here)

    self.last_time_called = timeit.default_timer()
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Performance of Approach 2

In Linux, this yields a median rate of 4488 packets/sec (0.26% error), which is on par with Windows but eats the CPU the same way, so it's really inefficient.

## The Question

Here's what I'm getting at. **How do we use `sleep()` in Linux to keep our CPU usage reasonable while still having decent timing accuracy?**

I figure this would have to involve some sort of monitoring and compensation process but I'm not really sure how to go about implementing such a thing. Is there a standard way to approach this kind of error-correction problem?

Comment: See [`nanosleep(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep).

Comment: See also [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) & [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Notice that Python is known to be slow. You might switch to compiled Ocaml or C++ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to guarantee this is to use real-time OS scheduling.  Otherwise, you are at the scheduler's mercy and could be preempted at any time (e.g. if there is some high-priority/low-nice process eating your CPU cycles).  Indeed, `sleep()` is just a convenient way to ask for a preemption of a specific duration.  It's always possible you will sleep for substantially longer than you ask.  This is why Windows does not even try to sleep for <1ms; it isn't capable of that level of precision once you factor in scheduler nondeterminism.  Out of the box, Linux isn't either, but it can be configured (via [`sched_setscheduler(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler)) to be real-time, so it will make the attempt if you ask.