# NodeJS and Socket.io Flood Control

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Recently I've been working on a small chat program that utilizes web sockets to send messages to others that are connected to the website.

It is currently working great, the only problem I have with this is flood control. People are able to spam the chat without being blocked.

Essentially what I am looking for is some ideas about on how to control spam (ie if they send x messages in x time, they will be limited for x amount of time).

Comment: Google ["rate limiting algorithm"](https://www.google.com/search?q=rate+limiting+algorithm&oq=rate+limiting+algorithm) and you will find all sorts of algorithm possibilities including this StackOverflow question: [What's a good rate limiting algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm).

Comment: Thank you that was helpful will implement this now! :) If you want post an answer so I can give you top answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you Google ["rate limiting algorithm"](https://www.google.com/search?q=rate%20limiting%20algorithm&oq=rate%20limiting%20algorithm), you will find all sorts of algorithm possibilities including this StackOverflow question: [What's a good rate limiting algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm)