# How to rate limit messages on SockJS (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockjs, rate-limiting

I'm working on a chat project based on Node.JS + SockJS (https://github.com/IgorAntun/node-chat) and I'm not sure on how to implement a rate limit so clients can't spam/flood the servers.
Example: User X sent over 5 messages in less than Y seconds, so he would get temp-banned for spamming or something like that.

What would be the best approach for that?

Comment: Also see [Introduction to Rate Limiting with Redis](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/introduction-to-rate-limiting-with-redis/155) and [Better Rate Limiting](http://engineering.classdojo.com/blog/2015/02/06/rolling-rate-limiter/) and [Node Rate Limiter](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter) or [Using NGINX proxy for Rate Limiting](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/).

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I got it working by adapting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm) to javascript :)