# Rate-limiting python decorator

Tags: python, algorithm, decorator, python-decorators, rate-limiting

I found [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/70/) rate-limiting python decorator based on *redis* classes. How can I write a similar decorator that uses only what's available in the standard library that can be used as follows?

```
def ratelimit(limit, every):
    #  python magic 

@ratelimit(limit=1, every=2)
def printlimited(x):
    print x

# print one number every two seconds
for x in range(10):
    printlimited(x)
```

*There are other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/667706/1003123) on stackoverflow but they do not allow to specify the denominator.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a [`threading.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) to count and block the requests that are exceeding the limit, in combination with [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) to schedule a function that releases the semaphore.

```
from threading import Semaphore, Timer
from functools import wraps

def ratelimit(limit, every):
    def limitdecorator(fn):
        semaphore = Semaphore(limit)
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            semaphore.acquire()
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:                    # don't catch but ensure semaphore release
                timer = Timer(every, semaphore.release)
                timer.setDaemon(True)   # allows the timer to be canceled on exit
                timer.start()
        return wrapper
    return limitdecorator
```

I extended this idea and published a library on PyPI named [limit](https://pypi.org/project/limit/).

Comment: This won't release the semaphore if the wrapped function throws an exception. You could use a `try..finally` clause to ensure that happens.