# Python decorator to limit rate of a function calls

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to implement a decorator that allows to limit the rate with which a function is executed.

I would like the decorator to start a timer when the function is called. If the function is called before the timer runs out, I'd like to **cancel the previous call** and restart the timer. When the timer ends, the function should run.

I've serched around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918772/rate-limiting-python-decorator) decorator. However, this decorator stops the execution of the program while the timer is running, which is something I need to avoid.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is rather complicated, but a simple idea is to start a timer thread and cancel it if the function is called again and start another timer thread.

now we need somewhere to store this timer ... so a dictionary should suffice, and to allow the user to choose the delay, we will just do a double wrap of functions.

```py
from threading import Timer
from functools import wraps
import time

functions_store = {}
def main_decorator(interval):
    def sub_decorator(fun):
        function_id = id(fun)  # since no two objects have the same id
        @wraps(fun)
        def new_fun(*args,**kwargs):
            if function_id in functions_store:
                functions_store[function_id].cancel()  # cancel old timer
            new_timer = Timer(interval,fun,args=args,kwargs=kwargs)  # make new timer
            functions_store[function_id] = new_timer  # store timer to stop it later
            new_timer.start()
        return new_fun
    return sub_decorator


@main_decorator(1) # must be called again before 1 second passes.
def func_to_run():
    print("hi")
    
func_to_run()
time.sleep(0.5)
func_to_run()
```

the word "hi" will be printed after 1.5 seconds instead of 1 second because we called the function again before it fired the first time.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it's exactly what I asked for. Unfortunately this does not work completely together within a `matplotlib`  interactive plot that's where I needed it, but this is most likely a different problem and was not part of the question.