# PHP Cookie to Track/Limit Website Joins (Preventing Automated Account Creation)

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I want to implement a solution to limit the number of Website Joins can be made by one user. I thought of tracking IP address but these are to generic now.

I'm now looking to set a cookie and increment for each join and then block joins at say 5 from one machine per day. Does anyone have any thoughts around this being a good/poor idea?

use something like:

```
setcookie("w3resource", $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/home/your_usename/", "example.com", 1, 1);
```

Is this a fair way to try to prevent automated account creations.

Then apart from a captcha (can anyone recommend one that is hard to break) what other measures could I use to prevent automated account creation?

thx

Comment: What happens when the user clears there cookies... this system would be very easy to bypass and going with IP would be a better solution

Comment: restricting people to 5 pageviews a day is a very strange thing to do tbh, you want as many page views as you can get per day, no? Google has a nice captcha system which doesn't even require user input. just a button click. thought I heared it was tough to crack. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically trying to **rate limit** access to your web application. There is a nice [article on codinghorror.com](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking/) showcasing the different options you have to rate limit.

Getting more technical you have to decide whether you want rate limiting to be done [by your web server](https://serverfault.com/questions/540743/how-to-rate-limit-apache-server-on-ip-basis) or by [your own implementation](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-rate-limiting-into-your-web-app-login--cms-22133).

If you roll your own solution, I'd recommend to have stacked rate limits. E.g. 5 sign up attempts per minute, if exceeded 20 per hour, if exceeded 30 per day, etc. Heres a [simple algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm) (albeit its written in python) that should get you going.