# Protecting express js server from brute force

Tags: node.js, api, express, brute-force

I'm writing an api using nodejs and express and my app is hosted by openshift free plan.
I want to protect my routes from brute force. For example if an IP sends more than 5 requests /sec then block it for 5 minutes. :)

Comment: This is called "Rate Limiting" and there have been many articles and some previous StackOverflow posts written about it.  I'd suggest you start with what has already been written.  Here's one: [What's a good rate limiting algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm).

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the name, I'm searching for it + it's very cool to write something from scratch :)

Comment: Here's a good reference on the [Leaky Bucket Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) which is one common algorithm used for rate limiting.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing stopping you from implementing this in Node.js/express directly, but this sort of thing is typically (and almost certainly more easily) handled by using something like `nginx` or Apache `httpd` to handle traffic to your app.

This has the added benefit of allowing you to run the app entirely as an unprivileged user because nginx (or whatever) will be binding to ports 80 and 443 (which requires administrative/superuser/whatever privileges) rather than your app. Plus you can easily get a bunch of other desirable features, like caching for static contents.

nginx has [a module specifically for this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html):

> The ngx_http_limit_req_module module (0.7.21) is used to limit the request processing rate per a defined key, in particular, the processing rate of requests coming from a single IP address.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I think that I didn't get your point. I'm using nodejs and don't want to using another webserver :)

Comment: It's standard practice to use nginx as a reverse proxy to node.

Answer (score 5):

There are several packages on NPM that are dedicated to this, if you are using the [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework:

- [express-rate-limiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit)
- [express-limiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-limiter)
- [express-brute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-brute)

These can be used for limiting by ip, but also by other information (e.g. by username for failed login attempts).

Answer (score 5):

It is better to limit rates on reverse-proxy, load balancer or any other entry point to your node.js app.

However, it doesn't fit requirements sometimes.

[rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) package has block option you need

```
const { RateLimiterMemory } = require('rate-limiter-flexible');

const opts = {
  points: 5, // 5 points
  duration: 1, // Per second
  blockDuration: 300, // block for 5 minutes if more than points consumed 
};

const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory(opts);

const rateLimiterMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // Consume 1 point for each request
  rateLimiter.consume(req.connection.remoteAddress)
    .then(() => {
      next();
    })
    .catch((rejRes) => {
      res.status(429).send('Too Many Requests');
    });
};

app.use(rateLimiterMiddleware);
```

You can configure `rate-limiter-flexible` for any exact route. See [official express docs about using middlwares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

There are also options for Cluster or distributed apps and many others useful