# Determine the rate limit for requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a question about rate limits. 
I take a data from the CSV and enter it into the query and the output is stored in a list. 
I get an error because I make too many requests at once.
(I can only make 20 requests per second). How can I determine the rate limit?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("Data_1000.csv")
list = []



def requestSummonerData(summonerName, APIKey):

    URL = "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + summonerName + "?api_key=" + APIKey
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return response.json()

def main():
    APIKey = (str)(input('Copy and paste your API Key here: '))

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        summonerName = row['Player_Name']
        responseJSON  = requestSummonerData(summonerName, APIKey)
        ID = responseJSON ['accountId']
        ID = int(ID)
        list.insert(index,ID)

    df["accountId"]= list
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good rate limiting algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you already know you can only make 20 requests per second, you just need to work out how long to wait between each request:

Divide 1 second by 20, which should give you 0.05. So you just need to sleep for 0.05 of a second between each request and you shouldn't hit the limit (maybe increase it a bit if you want to be safe).

`import time` at the top of your file and then `time.sleep(0.05)` inside of your `for` loop (you could also just do `time.sleep(1/20)`)

Comment: And if the rate limit would be 100 requests per 2 minutes? 
I have to do it that like that time.sleep(120/100) ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly! :)

Comment: This saved my bacon