# Rate limit api multi process

Tags: python, api, multiprocessing

I have a pretty straight forward code where I load a list if id's from a file and then iterate through each id in the list and call an api where i pass the id value and dump the api response content into a file.

I would like to speed this process up by doing parallel api calls, however the api server only allows 5 calls max per second. another key consideration is the api pull is slow, on average each call takes 10 seconds to finish.

I would like to be able to have multiple parallel process which have some way of ensuring that no more than 5 calls max occur in a single second.

This is the current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

ids = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

ids = ids['Id'].values.tolist()

def dump_data(df,idx):

    filename = base_dir+'\\'+str(idx)+'.csv'
    data.to_csv(filename, header= True, index=False) #write data to file

def get_api(idx):

   data = call_some_api(idx)  #api returns data as pandas dataframe, take about 10 secs
   dump_data(df,idx)


Parallel(n_jobs=10, verbose = 50)(delayed(get_api)(idx) for idx in ids)
```

I'm currently using joblib, but if there is a better library for this solution it can be used instead.

How can I ensure there will not be more than 5 requests going out at any given second? (while at he same time doing all the requests as fast as possible)

Also I'm using Python 3.9 on Windows

Comment: Do they have one of these headers in the response: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/rl-best-practices/

Comment: the response is something along the lines, of too many concurrent calls, pleas try back in xxx seconds

Comment: I mean in response **http headers** not in text

Comment: Use a rate limiting approach; there are libraries to do it, but requesting software/libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow; you should go searching for perhaps _python rate limit_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good rate limiting algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm)

Comment: code has been added for clarity

Comment: @balmy I think there was a misunderstanding, this question is not about sequential rate limiting, its about how to implement a rate limit when doing a parallel task

Comment: You can create a cron job that runs every second. You can send 5 api requests using twisted every sec. And make sure to all local operations gets completed in less than 750ms. we should have 250ms that can be reserve for the network layer.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2**

After rethinking this a bit more, it makes more sense to use either a standard multithreading pool or multiprocessing pool depending on your needs and to then pass to the worker function (either indirectly as a global or explicitly as an argument) a `CallingThrottle` instance whose `throttle` method can be called directly by the worker function at the precise point in processing that throttling needs to take place (right before making the request to the website). Passing the throttle instance directly as an argument to your worker function should allow you to use this with `joblib` (but I would think in your case all you need is a multithreading pool).

For example:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from threading import Lock
import time

class CallingThrottle:
    def __init__(self, nb_call_times_limit, expired_time):
        self.nb_call_times_limit = nb_call_times_limit
        self.expired_time = expired_time
        self.called_timestamps = list()
        self.lock = Lock()

    def throttle(self):
        with self.lock:
            while len(self.called_timestamps) == self.nb_call_times_limit:
                now = time.time()
                self.called_timestamps = list(filter(
                    lambda x: now - x < self.expired_time,
                    self.called_timestamps
                ))
                if len(self.called_timestamps) == self.nb_call_times_limit:
                    time_to_sleep = self.called_timestamps[0] + self.expired_time - now
                    time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
            self.called_timestamps.append(time.time())

# A "managed" CallingThrottle is required for use with multiprocessing:
class CallingThrottleManager(BaseManager):
    pass

CallingThrottleManager.register('CallingThrottle', CallingThrottle)

def init_pool(throttle):
    global calling_throttle

    calling_throttle = throttle

def worker(x):
    """
    Emulate a task that takes 10 seconds to execute.
    Cannot run more than 5 of these per second.
    """
    from datetime import datetime
    calling_throttle.throttle()
    print(datetime.now(), 'x =', x)
    time.sleep(10)
    return x, x * x

def main():
    # Multithreading example:
    calling_throttle = CallingThrottle(5, 1) # 5 calls every 1 second
    pool = ThreadPool(20)
    init_pool(calling_throttle)
    start = time.time()
    results = pool.map(worker, range(20))
    print('Total elapsed time:', time.time() - start)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print('\n', '-' * 30, '\n', sep='')

    # Multiprocessing example:
    with CallingThrottleManager() as manager:
        calling_throttle = manager.CallingThrottle(5, 1) # 5 calls every 1 second
        pool = Pool(20, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(calling_throttle,))
        start = time.time()
        results = pool.map(worker, range(20))
        print('Total elapsed time:', time.time() - start)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To use a throttle with `joblib`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

from threading import Lock
import time

class CallingThrottle:
    def __init__(self, nb_call_times_limit, expired_time):
        self.nb_call_times_limit = nb_call_times_limit
        self.expired_time = expired_time
        self.called_timestamps = list()
        self.lock = Lock()

    def throttle(self):
        with self.lock:
            while len(self.called_timestamps) == self.nb_call_times_limit:
                now = time.time()
                self.called_timestamps = list(filter(
                    lambda x: now - x < self.expired_time,
                    self.called_timestamps
                ))
                if len(self.called_timestamps) == self.nb_call_times_limit:
                    time_to_sleep = self.called_timestamps[0] + self.expired_time - now
                    time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
            self.called_timestamps.append(time.time())

# A "managed" CallingThrottle is required for use with multiprocessing:
class CallingThrottleManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def dump_data(df, idx):
    filename = base_dir+'\\'+str(idx)+'.csv'
    data.to_csv(filename, header= True, index=False) #write data to file

def get_api(calling_throttle, idx):
    calling_throttle.throttle()
    data = call_some_api(idx)  #api returns data as pandas dataframe, take about 10 secs
    dump_data(df, idx)


def main():
    ids = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    ids = ids['Id'].values.tolist()

    CallingThrottleManager.register('CallingThrottle', CallingThrottle)

    with CallingThrottleManager() as manager:
        calling_throttle = manager.CallingThrottle()
        Parallel(n_jobs=10, verbose = 50)(delayed(get_api)(calling_throttle, idx) for idx in ids)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Update 1**

I originally implemented the [rate-limiting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm) that was referenced in the comment made by @balmy and it was noticed that there are times where the rate can be exceeded. This phenomenon was commented upon by @mindvirus where the OP was trying for 5 messages in an 8 second period:

> This is good, but can exceed the rate. Let's say at time 0 you forward 5 messages, then at time N * (8/5) for N = 1, 2, ... you can send another message, resulting in more than 5 messages in an 8 second period.

So I am now using a new rate-limiting algorithm.

---

I have created two classes, `RateLimitedProcessPool` and `RateLimitedThreadPool` for mulitprocessing and multithreading respectively based on the algorithm presented in [What's a good rate limiting algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm). These classes are like the standard `mulitprocessing.pool.Pool` and `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` classes except the `__init__` methods take two extra keyword arguments *rate* and *per* that together specify the maximum rate per second that the `apply_async` method can be called. For example, values *rate=7* and *per=3* implies that successive calls to `apply_async` will throttle so as to only allow a maximum rate of 7 calls every 3 seconds.

The following code demonstrates this with a simple worker function that emulates the OP's situation where the worker function takes 10 seconds to execute and must be limited to a maximum rate of 5 calls per second. We need to invoke this function 20 times and so the best performance we can achieve is a total run time of approximately 13 seconds.

```py
import multiprocessing.pool
import multiprocessing
import threading
from functools import wraps
import time

class CallingThrottle:
    def __init__(self, nb_call_times_limit, expired_time):
        self.nb_call_times_limit = nb_call_times_limit
        self.expired_time = expired_time
        self.called_timestamps = list()

    def __enter__(self):
        while len(self.called_timestamps) == self.nb_call_times_limit:
            now = time.time()
            self.called_timestamps = list(filter(
                lambda x: now - x < self.expired_time,
                self.called_timestamps
            ))
            if len(self.called_timestamps) == self.nb_call_times_limit:
                time_to_sleep = self.called_timestamps[0] + self.expired_time - now
                time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
        self.called_timestamps.append(time.time())

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        pass

class RateLimitedPool:
    def __init__(self, rate, per):
        self.calling_throttle = CallingThrottle(rate, per)
        self.first_time = True

    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # There could be a lag between the first call to apply_async
        # and the first task actually starting, so set the first time
        # after the call to apply_async:
        if self.first_time:
            self.first_time = False
            async_result = super().apply_async(*args, **kwargs)
            with self.calling_throttle:
                pass
            return async_result
        else:
            with self.calling_throttle:
                return super().apply_async(*args, **kwargs)

class RateLimitedProcessPool(RateLimitedPool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, rate=5, per=1, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        RateLimitedPool.__init__(self, rate, per)

class RateLimitedProcessPool(RateLimitedPool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, rate=5, per=1, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        RateLimitedPool.__init__(self, rate, per)

class RateLimitedThreadPool(RateLimitedPool, multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool):
    def __init__(self, *args, rate=5, per=1, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        RateLimitedPool.__init__(self, rate, per)

def threadpool(pool):
    def decorate(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return pool.apply_async(f, args, kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorate

def processpool(pool):
    def decorate(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return pool.apply_async(f, args, kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorate

########################################


def worker(x):
    """
    Emulate a task that takes 10 seconds to execute.
    Cannot run more than 5 of these per second.
    """
    from datetime import datetime
    print(datetime.now(), 'x =', x)
    time.sleep(10)
    return x, x * x

def main():
    args = range(20)
    pool = RateLimitedThreadPool(20, rate=5, per=1) # 5 per second
    start = time.time()
    for x in args:
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(x,))
    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('Total elapsed time:', time.time() - start)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
2021-10-03 07:19:48.002628 x =  0
2021-10-03 07:19:48.002628 x =  1
2021-10-03 07:19:48.002628 x =  3
2021-10-03 07:19:48.002628 x =  4
2021-10-03 07:19:48.002628 x =  2
2021-10-03 07:19:49.005625 x =  5
2021-10-03 07:19:49.005625 x =  6
2021-10-03 07:19:49.005625 x =  8
2021-10-03 07:19:49.005625 x =  7
2021-10-03 07:19:49.005625 x =  9
2021-10-03 07:19:50.008775 x =  10
2021-10-03 07:19:50.008775 x =  11
2021-10-03 07:19:50.008775 x =  13
2021-10-03 07:19:50.008775 x =  12
2021-10-03 07:19:50.008775 x =  14
2021-10-03 07:19:51.012774 x =  15
2021-10-03 07:19:51.012774 x =  16
2021-10-03 07:19:51.012774 x =  17
2021-10-03 07:19:51.012774 x =  18
2021-10-03 07:19:51.012774 x =  19
Total elapsed time: 13.015560150146484
```

**CPU Intensive Example**

In the following example I am using a `RateLimitedProcessPool` since my worker function is 100% CPU taking approximately 10 seconds to execute on my desktop. I only have 8 logical cores (4 physical cores), so my pool size is 8 and for this demo I am submitting 8 tasks with a rate of 3 tasks per second. The second 3 tasks will start approximately 1 second after the first 3 and the next 2 tasks will start 1 second after that. Because the number of physical cores becomes a limiting factor, the total running time is a little over 21 seconds.

```py
import multiprocessing.pool
import multiprocessing
import threading
from functools import wraps
import time

class RateLimitedPool:
    # There is an a lag between the first call to apply_async and the first task actually starting:
    LAG_TIME = .2 # seconds - needs to be fine-tuned:

    def __init__(self, rate, per):
        assert isinstance(rate, int) and rate > 0
        assert isinstance(per, (int, float)) and per > 0
        self.rate = rate
        self.per = per
        self.count = 0
        self.start_time = None
        self.first_time = True

    def _check_allowed(self):
        current_time = time.time()
        if self.start_time is None:
            self.start_time = current_time
            self.count = 1
            return True
        elapsed_time = current_time - self.start_time
        if self.first_time:
            elapsed_time -= self.LAG_TIME
        if elapsed_time >= self.per:
            self.start_time = current_time
            self.count = 1
            self.first_time = False
            return True
        if self.count < self.rate:
            self.count += 1
            return True
        return False

    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while not self._check_allowed():
            time.sleep(.1) # This can be fine-tuned
        return super().apply_async(*args, **kwargs)

class RateLimitedProcessPool(RateLimitedPool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, rate=5, per=1, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        RateLimitedPool.__init__(self, rate, per)

class RateLimitedThreadPool(RateLimitedPool, multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool):
    def __init__(self, *args, rate=5, per=1, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        RateLimitedPool.__init__(self, rate, per)

def threadpool(pool):
    def decorate(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return pool.apply_async(f, args, kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorate

def processpool(pool):
    def decorate(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return pool.apply_async(f, args, kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorate

########################################

ONE_SECOND_ITERATIONS = 20_000_000

def one_second():
    sum = 0
    for _ in range(ONE_SECOND_ITERATIONS):
        sum += 1
    return sum

def worker(x):
    """
    Emulate a task that takes 10 seconds to execute.
    Cannot run more than 3 of these per second.
    """
    from datetime import datetime
    print(datetime.now(), 'x = ', x)
    for _ in range(10):
        one_second()
    return x, x * x

def main():
    args = range(8)
    pool = RateLimitedProcessPool(8, rate=3, per=1) # 3 per second
    start = time.time()
    for x in args:
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(x,))
    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('Total elapsed time:', time.time() - start)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
2021-10-03 09:51:32.857166 x =  0
2021-10-03 09:51:32.859168 x =  1
2021-10-03 09:51:32.864166 x =  2
2021-10-03 09:51:33.899890 x =  5
2021-10-03 09:51:33.899890 x =  3
2021-10-03 09:51:33.907888 x =  4
2021-10-03 09:51:34.924889 x =  6
2021-10-03 09:51:34.925888 x =  7
Total elapsed time: 21.22123622894287
```

Comment: Appreciate your code! One question; How is the `threadpool` function interacting with the rest of the code?

Comment: It's not; it's just a definition you can use if you want to have a rate-limited multithreading pool and is there for completeness. To support multithreading also is the reason for the common `RateLimitedPool` base class.

Comment: I have updated the answer with **Update 2** at the top of the answer. This is simpler, more direct and should be usable with `joblib`.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to use the concurrent.futures library and a loop that will run 5 threads at a time, i have limited the number of worker threads to 50 but this can probably be higher as the threads are not doing any cpu intensive tasks.
with the last sleep(1) statement you are guaranteed to get around or just under 5 calls per second (because of the loop processing time)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures, time

ids = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

ids = ids['Id'].values.tolist()

def dump_data(df,idx):
    filename = base_dir+'\\'+str(idx)+'.csv'
    data.to_csv(filename, header= True, index=False) #write data to file

def get_api(idx):
    data = call_some_api(idx)  #api returns data as pandas dataframe, take about 10 secs
    dump_data(df,idx)

N = 5 # number of requests per second
L = 10 # latency per request

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N*L) as ex:
    # reshape IDs into a list of lists of N items each and loop over them
    for id_list in ((ids[i] for i in range(j*N,min(j*N+N,len(ids))) ) for j in range(round(len(ids)/N+0.5)) )

        # wait if there are items on the work queue 
        while ex._work_queue.qsize()>0: time.sleep(1)   

        ex.map(get_api,id_list)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could get real fancy with something like this, but I doubt you'll get significantly better performance than something dumb and simple like just submitting each task to a processing pool with a 1/5th of a second delay. It would be worth testing if your api call releases the GIL, because using 1 thread per active call (in flight) is much less resource intensive than 1 process per active call (though it still may be fine.. hardware is cheap right?).

One potential issue I can see with this is if a particular batch of calls takes a long time, and the input queue of the pool starts filling up, once the slow tasks complete, you may end up submitting too many at once. An easy solution that may solve this would be to just provision the processing pool with more workers than you really need. If the average call lasts 10 sec, and you submit 5/sec you'd need 50 workers. You could fairly easily just give the pool 100 workers, and as long as the api call isn't too cpu intensive this would only be ram inefficient.

The other potential issue you may run into is that the endpoint may only allow a certain number of simultaneous connections, which may at times be less than the number of calls in flight you want to have. The solution to this would be to limit the number of pool workers to the maximum number of connections, but this conflicts with the solution to the earlier problem.

Here's how I would solve both: give a pool workers an input queue of limited size so the main thread can't pile up a bunch of jobs in the input queue. Here's how I would do that:

```py
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep

def dump_data(df,idx):
    filename = base_dir+'\\'+str(idx)+'.csv'
    data.to_csv(filename, header= True, index=False) #write data to file

def get_api(idx):
   data = call_some_api(idx)  #api returns data as pandas dataframe, take about 10 secs
   dump_data(df,idx)

class STOPFLAG: pass

def worker(in_q):
    while True:
        task = in_q.get()
        if isinstance(task, STOPFLAG):
            return
        get_api(task)

def main():
    # int: n tasks per float: t seconds
    n = 5 #tasks per interval
    t = 1.0 #interval in seconds
    max_in_flight = 20 #limited to 20 concurrent connections
    
    ids = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    ids = ids['Id'].values.tolist()
    
    work_q = Queue(maxsize=1) #maxsize will cause q.put() to block until it's got space to put something
    
    pool = [Process(target=worker, args=(work_q,)) for _ in range(max_in_flight)]
    for p in pool: p.start()
    
    for idx in ids:
        work_q.put(idx)
        sleep(t/n) #dumb but effective rate limit
    
    for p in pool: work_q.put(STOPFLAG())
    for p in pool: p.join() #I p in pools :P
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If your api endpoint returns rate limit headers, you could fairly easily modify the code to continually update a few shared values from the workers so the main thread could decide more intelligently when (and how many) to launch tasks:

```py
from multiprocessing import Value
def worker(in_q, Value: limit, Value: remaining, Value: reset):
    while True:
        task = in_q.get()
        if isinstance(task, STOPFLAG):
            return
        response = get_api(task)
        if "X-Rate-Limit-Limit" in response.headers:
            with limit.get_lock(): #beyond 3.5 you can just call "with limit:" to acquire the lock for synchronization
                limit.value = response.headers["X-Rate-Limit-Limit"]
        # same for "X-Rate-Limit-Remaining" and "X-Rate-Limit-Reset"

#then in main:

    #...
    for idx in ids:
        #get most recent number of remaining connections allowed:
        with remaining.get_lock():
            n = remaining.value
        if n > 0:
            work_q.put(idx)
        else:
            with reset.get_lock():
                sleeptime = reset.value - time.time()
            sleep(sleeptime) #maybe add an extra bit of sleep time to account for possible clock mismatch
```

Comment: I deleted my answer realizing that my answer was based on timing submissions to a processing/threading pool but once those tasks were submitted I really had no control over the scheduling of those tasks. I just saw your just post now (a bit late). I probably won't have a chance to look at this until tomorrow (again probably too late for any bonus).

Comment: @Booboo iirc rate limiting usually supports x-rate-limit headers, which I provided an example for. Otherwise, no algorithm is going to be perfect anyway because most computers don't have an atomic clock to handle perfect time sync. Without rate limit feedback from the server or knowing how the limiting is implemented it is all but impossible to do it "perfectly" and rather (imao) probably just best to settle for simple and close enough (maybe try to stay slightly under the rate limit so time jitter doesn't cause a bunch-up)

Comment: (1) I think you need to remove the `global` statement in function `worker`. (2) Your program has the same property as mine in that you can control the frequency in which tasks are submitted to the queue, but once you have done that the scheduling of those tasks is out of your hands. For example:, to keep it very simple: in `main` set `ids = range(30)` and in `get_api` simply print the current time and value of `idx` and then `sleep(10 - idx/3)`.  For me tasks 20 through 25 (6 tasks) started within a 5 second interval  as well as the first 6 tasks (due to some initial latency?).

Comment: 1: yup..my b. I had a solution with mp.Pool earlier that I didn't clean up after. 2: Any solution that doesn't take direct feedback from the server would need to set an interval some degree slower than the true rate limit because of time sync / network latency issues. I could not replicate a significant startup delay with similar test code, and the intervals were all accurate (no more than 5 tasks ever started within any 1 second interval). This was however why I eliminated `mp.Pool`, and used a input queue `maxsize=1`, so jobs couldn't pile up, then get released all at once.

Comment: @Booboo I suppose I could also add a lock to block the main process until the task was received from the queue as well... in that case I don't see how the threshold could be exceeded beyond whatever latency / time jitter is introduced by the api call itself. That said however breaks into the diminishing returns thing again however, as we cannot control the time jitter of the network stack etc... All that gets back to my earliest statement that even the most complicated system may not perform much better than just setting a simple time division slightly slower than the true limit.

Comment: I've added a new answer, which I believe solves the issues.

Answer (score -1):

The only reasonably accurate way to do this is to perform the rate-limiting algorithm at the point where the worker function is about to call the API that requires the rate-limiting. When you attempt to do this at task submission the problem becomes that you have no control over how the tasks are ultimately scheduled and you can no longer guarantee that the number of API calls per second will be achieved. But to move the algorithm out to each process means that you must now use values in shared memory with locking to ensure everything works correctly.

This is achieved by the `RateLimiter` class that creates two shared memory values, one to hold a count of the number of API calls that have been made in the current interval and and another to hold the time that the current interval expiries. Each process in the pool is initialized with a global variable that is an instance of this `RateInstance` class that contain references to these shared variables:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, Value
import time

class RateLimiter:
    FUDGE_FACTOR = .0015 # due to imprecision of timer: 15ms.

    def __init__(self, rate, per):
        assert isinstance(rate, int) and rate > 0
        assert isinstance(per, (int, float)) and per > 0
        self._rate = rate
        self._per = per
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._count = Value('i', False) # 0
        self._expiration = Value('d', False) # 0.0

    def __call__(self, api_func, *args, **kwargs):
        with self._lock:
            now = time.time()
            if now >= self._expiration.value:
                self._expiration.value = now + self._per + self.FUDGE_FACTOR
                self._count.value = 1
            elif self._count.value < self._rate:
                self._count.value += 1
            else:
                time.sleep(self._expiration.value - now)
                self._expiration.value = time.time() + self._per + self.FUDGE_FACTOR
                self._count.value = 1
        return api_func(*args, **kwargs)

def init_pool(the_rate_limiter):
    global rate_limiter
    rate_limiter = the_rate_limiter

def api_func(x):
    from datetime import datetime
    print(datetime.now(), 'x = ', x)
    time.sleep(10 - x/3)
    return x * x

def worker(x):
    return rate_limiter(api_func, x)

def main():
    # 5 api calls per second
    rate_limiter = RateLimiter(5, 1.0)
    pool = Pool(20, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(rate_limiter,))
    results = pool.map(worker, range(20))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
2021-10-04 07:12:32.148725 x =  0
2021-10-04 07:12:32.171724 x =  3
2021-10-04 07:12:32.172724 x =  2
2021-10-04 07:12:32.173724 x =  1
2021-10-04 07:12:32.175724 x =  4
2021-10-04 07:12:33.151015 x =  7
2021-10-04 07:12:33.151015 x =  8
2021-10-04 07:12:33.151015 x =  5
2021-10-04 07:12:33.151015 x =  9
2021-10-04 07:12:33.152014 x =  6
2021-10-04 07:12:34.154015 x =  14
2021-10-04 07:12:34.154015 x =  13
2021-10-04 07:12:34.154015 x =  10
2021-10-04 07:12:34.155014 x =  12
2021-10-04 07:12:34.156015 x =  11
2021-10-04 07:12:35.155018 x =  16
2021-10-04 07:12:35.156014 x =  19
2021-10-04 07:12:35.156014 x =  17
2021-10-04 07:12:35.156014 x =  15
2021-10-04 07:12:35.157015 x =  18
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361]
```